# How to create a test user in seeds.rb using user authentication (Monban)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using Monban for user authentication and want to create a test user in seeds.rb for development.  Currently I have this in seeds.rb:

```
include Monban::ControllerHelpers      #I tried with and without this
@user = sign_up({name: 'foo', email: 'foo@bar.com', password: '123'})
```

So far can't get it to work.  How do you create a test user when you need to 'digest' the password using something like Monban?

Comment: Whats the error you're seeing?

Comment: undefined method 'helper_method' for Object:Class

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SignUp service object

https://github.com/halogenandtoast/monban/blob/master/lib/monban/controller_helpers/sign_up.rb

```
SignUp.new({name: 'foo', email: 'foo@bar.com', password: '123'}).perform
```

and if you want to  make it look nicer just define the sign_up method yourself

```
def sign_up(user_params)
  SignUp.new(user_params).perform
end
```

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any other Monban related questions.

Comment: As an aside, I'll probably be moving these from the controller_helpers directory to a services directory. They are definitely misnamed here.